# Vitest Mock for path.join in __Mocks__ folder

Tags: javascript, mocking, vitest

I want to convert my mock implementation for path (specifically "join") in to a __mocks__ folder in a file called path.js

Currently I have this in my io.test.js file and it works:

```js
vi.mock("path", () => {
  return {
    default: {
      join: (...args) => {
        return args[args.length - 1];
      },
    },
  };
});
```

How would I do this in the __mocks__\path.js file instead?

Answer (score 1):

Vitest would normally look for the mock file with the same name as the mocked one in the `__mocks__` folder under the project root folder. However I've found this a bit problematic, as on one hand having an additional root folder like that, instead for example one under `test` folder may not be what everyone wants (ugly?), but more importantly sometimes the name of the original import is not trivial to guess, e.g. for modules from `node_modules`, most the time the import path may not really be a filename, so what the file under `__mocks__` should be called can become tedious guess-game...

Instead one can use this syntax to use a file based mock from any location:

```js
// The test file

vi.mock('path', async () =>
  await vi.importActual('another/path/to/the/mock.js')
)
```

```js
// another/path/to/the/mock.js

export default {
  join: (...args) => {
    return args[args.length - 1];
  },
}
```

Having it set up like this you can put the mock file anywhere you want.

Note that mocks under the root `__mocks__` would however be automatically picked up by Vitest, so using the same folder for these kind of manual mocks can lead to confusion. I'd recommend puting them under another folder. For me `test/vitest/mocks` or similar seems more logical.